# How can I add a view made in Angular in a ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I have a project made in ASP.NET, but I made a "game" in Angular and I want it to add it in a route of the main project, like: "home/game". Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your RouteConfig add this

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Game",
                url: "home/game/{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "GameController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

basically it catches all routes with a path contains home/game, since you're doing a SPA development.

And a controller for it and name it GameController